# How to execute for statement when we have different datamember in the object of the data contract?

Tags: c#, wcf

I have created an API which contains request and response data contract. This API get the response as note line. I have a request data which contains data member as

- cardNumber
- methodID
- noteline1, noteline2, ..., noteline18

I have a response data contract which contains 18 data members as noteline1, noteline2, ..., noteline18. The code is as below:

```
public CBNotesInqAndMaintResponse CBNote(CBNotesInqAndMaintRequest request)
{
    CBNotesInqAndMaintResponse response;
    try
    {
        var processCardBaseEnquiry = new CBNotesInqAndMaint();
        request.methodID = "01";
        response = processCardBaseEnquiry.Execute(request, clientIpAddress);
        processCardBaseEnquiry = null;
        return response;
    }
    catch(Exception ex){}

    if (response != null)
    {
        if (response.noteLine1 != null || response.noteLine1 != "")
        {
            request.methodID = "02";
            request.noteLine1 = response.noteLine1;
            processCardBaseEnquiry.Execute(request, clientIpAddress);
        }
        else if (response.noteLine2 != null || response.noteLine2 != "")
        {
            request.methodID = "02";
            response.noteLine2 = response.noteLine2;
            processCardBaseEnquiry.Execute(request, clientIpAddress);
        }

    // now I want to assign values to the request data from the response 
    // that I have received with methodID="02" and again execute the 
    // service to return the desired response. 

    ...
}
```

I wanted to do it with the help of for loop as it should reduce the line of code. How will I use the for loop  by assigning value of noteline text

Comment: Proper formatting of code for questions is easy to learn, and might help readers understand your question more quickly.

Comment: Hi! You've been a member of SO for quite some time now, and you should have picked up on how to use the question editor better. Please consider better formatting for your code snippet as that will - as crashmstr said - help us better understand you.

Answer (score 2):

Something similar to this?

```
//----------------------
//Response class
public class Responce
{
    List<string> MyData {get;set;}

    public Response()
    {
        MyData = new List<string>();
    }
}

//----------------------
//create response
var response = Response();
MyData.Add("result 1");
MyData.Add("result 2");

//----------------------
//and then later when you process it
var data = responce.MyData
foreach(string line in data)
{
    if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(line)
        continue;

    //do your processing
}
```